# How many float multiplies can be performed with a single core of the current Intel architectures?

Tags: x86, floating-point, cpu-architecture, simd, flops

Trying to assess the performance gain from an embedded architecture I tried to search for the number of **floating point** multiplies that can be performed in a cycle on a single core of the Core 2 and Core i7 architectures, but could not find a quick answer to that. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the ISA so I cannot tell that from looking at the respective instructions. I assume it would be some kind of a SIMD instruction. Any idea?

Comment: Related: [FLOPS per cycle for sandy-bridge and haswell SSE2/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655835) (but not a duplicate because FMA is counted as 2 FLOPs, and this wants only multiplies not adds or FMAs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing: Core 2 is ***not*** Intel's latest architecture. That would be Sandy Bridge.

Core 2 and Core i7 Nehalem, can sustain **1 SSE multiply/cycle**. Each SSE instruction can handle up to 4 single-precision or 2 double-precision. So that's **2 DP or 4 SP floating-point multiplies per cycle**.

Core i7 Sandy Bridge can sustain **1 AVX multiply/cycle**. AVX is double the size of SSE. So that's **4 DP or 8 SP floating-point multiplies per cycle**.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that current AMD processors offer the same performance?

Comment: Correct. I think all AMD processors since the K10 architecture have had the same SSE throughputs. (1 SSE multiply/cycle) For the new Bulldozer architecture, it's a little more complicated than that due the shared FPU between each "Bulldozer Module".