# Ops per cycle ARM Cortex CPUs?

Tags: arm, cpu, hardware

I need the number of operations per cycle that an ARM processor can execute, in particular those of Cortex-A7, Cortex-A9 and Cortex-A15.
I can't find anything online!

Thank you

EDIT: I need it for calculating the theoretical peak performance.

Comment: What do you consider an *operation*?

Answer (score 4):

I have not looked into integers yet but for single and double floating operations per cycle this is what I have come up with so far (from [flops-per-cycle-for-sandy-bridge-and-haswell-sse2-avx-avx2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655835/flops-per-cycle-for-sandy-bridge-and-haswell-sse2-avx-avx2/15657772#15657772.), [peak-flops-per-cycle-for-arm11-and-cortex-a7-cores-in-raspberry-pi-1-and-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976071/peak-flops-per-cycle-for-arm11-and-cortex-a7-cores-in-raspberry-pi-1-and-2), and [Cortex-A9 NEON Media Processing Engine Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0409i/index.html)).

Cortex-A7:

- 0.5 DP FLOPs/cycle: scalar VMLA.F64 every four cycles.
- 1.0 DP FLOPs/cycle: scalar VADD.F64 every cycle.
- 2.0 SP FLOPs/cycle: scalar VMLA.F32 every cycle.
- 2.0 SP FLOPs/cycle: 2-wide VMLA.F32 every other cycle.

Cortex-A9:

- 1.5 DP FLOPs/cycle: scalar VMLA.F64 + scalar VADD.F64 every other cycle.
- 4.0 SP FLOPs/cycle: 2-wide VMLA.F32 every cycle.

Cortex-A15:

- 2.0 DP FLOPs/cycle: scalar VMLA.F64 (or VFMA.F64) every cycle.
- 8.0 SP FLOPs/cycle: 4-wide VMLA.F32 (or VFMA.F32) every cycle.

One interesting observation is that Neon floating point no faster than VFP for the Cortex-A7.

Comment: It's slightly misleading to quote 1 DP FLOP/cycle for Cortex-A7.  Generally speaking when people talk about FLOPs without further context, the intended meaning is really "for a 50/50 mix of multiplies and adds", because that's what GEMM does (and not far off from an FFT, though good FFTs are usually slightly add-biased).

Comment: @StephenCanon, good point, I debated this. I actually had the VMLA.F64 there but removed it. Let me put it back.

Comment: @StephenCanon, I wonder if I made a wrong conclusion. I ran the code at http://nullprogram.com/blog/2015/07/10/ and I get about a factor of two speed up with Neon on my Raspberry Pi2 both with GCC 4.6 (raspian) and GCC 5.2 (arch). I have not done robust tests on the timing (the authors timing numbers have a large margin of error) but it seems to be about a factor of two which means Neon is faster that VFP on the Cortex-A7. Note that I have little time until October for much SOing so I won't be responding much until then.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the most common places.

You have it there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures