# Why is vectorization, faster in general, than loops?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, vectorization, simd, low-level

Why, at the lowest level of the hardware performing operations and the general underlying operations involved (i.e.: things general to all programming languages' actual implementations when running code), is vectorization typically so dramatically faster than looping?

What does the computer do when looping that it doesn't do when using vectorization (I'm talking about the actual computations that the computer performs, not what the programmer writes), or what does it do differently?

I have been unable to convince myself why the difference should be so significant.  I could probably be persuaded that vectorized code shaves off some looping overhead somewhere, but the computer still has to perform the same number of operations, doesn't it?  For example, if we're multiplying a vector of size N by a scalar, we'll have N multiplications to perform either way, won't we?

Comment: Hardware can be parallel. You can xor two 32 bit numbers in 1 cycle. You can xor two 1048576 bit numbers in still 1 cycle. Just burn a few more wires onto the chip.

Comment: With modern short-vector SIMD, you use vectors inside a loop to process a whole array.  Old-style Cray vector machines could set up for a big operation and then one instruction would load / operate / store, but that's not how x86 SSE / ARM NEON / PowerPC AltiVec work.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Vectorization (as the term is normally used) refers to SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) operation.

That means, in essence, that one instruction carries out the same operation on a number of operands in parallel. For example, to multiply a vector of size N by a scalar, let's call M the number of operands that size that it can operate on simultaneously. If so, then the number of instructions it needs to execute is approximately N/M, where (with purely scalar operations) it would have to carry out N operations.

For example, Intel's current AVX 2 instruction set uses 256-bit registers. These can be used to hold (and operate on) a set of 4 operands of 64-bits apiece, or 8 operands of 32 bits apiece.

So, assuming you're dealing with 32-bit, single-precision real numbers, that means a single instruction can do 8 operations (multiplications, in your case) at once, so (at least in theory) you can finish N multiplications using only N/8 multiplication instructions. At least, in theory, this should allow the operation to finish about 8 times as fast as executing one instruction at a time would allow.

Of course, the exact benefit depends on how many operands you support per instruction. Intel's first attempts only supported 64-bit registers, so to operate on 8 items at once, those items could only be 8 bits apiece. They currently support 256-bit registers, and they've announced support for 512-bit (and they may have even shipped that in a few high-end processors, but not in normal consumer processors, at least yet). Making good use of this capability can also be non-trivial, to put it mildly. Scheduling instructions so you actually have N operands available and in the right places at the right times isn't necessarily an easy task (at all).

To put things in perspective, the (now ancient) Cray 1 gained a lot of its speed exactly this way. Its vector unit operated on sets of 64 registers of 64 bits apiece, so it could do 64 double-precision operations per clock cycle. On optimally vectorized code, it was much closer to the speed of a current CPU than you might expect based solely on its (much lower) clock speed. Taking full advantage of that wasn't always easy though (and still isn't).

Keep in mind, however, that vectorization is *not* the only way in which a CPU can carry out operations in parallel. There's also the possibility of instruction-level parallelism, which allows a single CPU (or the single core of a CPU) to execute more than one instruction at a time. Most modern CPUs include hardware to (theoretically) execute up to around 4 instructions per clock cycle<sup>1</sup> if the instructions are a mix of loads, stores, and ALU.  They can fairly routinely execute close to 2 instructions per clock on average, or more in well-tuned loops when memory isn't a bottleneck.

Then, of course, there's multi-threading--running multiple streams of instructions on (at least logically) separate processors/cores.

So, a modern CPU might have, say, 4 cores, each of which can execute 2 vector multiplies per clock, and each of those instructions can operate on 8 operands. So, at least in theory, it can be carrying out 4 * 2 * 8 = 64 operations per clock.

Some instructions have better or worse throughput.  For example, FP adds throughput is lower than FMA or multiply on Intel before Skylake (1 vector per clock instead of 2).  But boolean logic like AND or XOR has 3 vectors per clock throughput; it doesn't take many transistors to build an AND/XOR/OR execution unit, so CPUs replicate them.  Bottlenecks on the total pipeline width (the front-end that decodes and issues into the out-of-order part of the core) are common when using high-throughput instructions, rather than bottlenecks on a specific execution unit.

---

1. But, over time CPUs tend to have more resources available, so this number rises.

Comment: In my introductory computer systems course (and in our parallel programming course), we treated a processor (or a single core of a multi-core CPU) as a black box sort of system that can ONLY do things sequentially; no computations could be simultaneously computed.  Is that incorrect?  Or does the core have its own sub-processors that can each do simple computations?

Comment: Yes, with respect to a modern (reasonably high-end) processor that's incorrect. Mainstream desktop/server CPUs have supported various types of parallelism for decades. Purely sequential would be (for example) a 486, but was no longer true of the original Pentium. On mainframes, the same things happened even longer ago (e.g., the CDC 6500 had an architecture similar to a Pentium, and the 6600 similar to a Pentium Pro). Those were released around 1964 or so.

Comment: Most modern CPUs have a pipeline width of 4 uops (Intel since Core2, AMD since Bulldozer).  That gives you 4 instructions per clock if you have mix of loads, stores, and single-uop ALU instructions.  (compare+branch instruction pairs can fuse into 1 uop, so Haswell's true max IPC is 6 instructions per clock, but much more realistic to just say 4.)  Ryzen's pipeline is 6-wide, but single-uop instructions can only run 5 per clock.  (AVX/AVX2 256b vectors decode to 2 uops and can fill up the pipe nicely.)  Core2 is unlikely to do 4 IPC except on specially crafted loops, but it's realistic on SKL.

Comment: A load+ALU instruction like `vfmadd132ps ymm0, ymm1, [rdi]` can fuse into a single uop, so you can sometimes saturate the vector ALUs and squeeze in loads to give them new data without bottlenecking on the front-end.  For example, I managed to construct a loop that runs 7 unfused-domain uops per clock on Skylake (2 micro-fused load+ALU, 1 store (which is 2 uops micro-fused into 1 on Intel), and one compare+branch.  http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#857.

Answer (score 18):

Vectorization has two main benefits.

1. The primary benefit is that hardware designed to support vector instructions generally has hardware that is capable of performing multiple ALU operations in parallel when vector instructions are used. For example, if you ask it to perform 16 additions with a 16-element vector instruction, it may have 16 adders that can do all the additions at once, in parallel. The *only* way to access all those adders<sup>1</sup> is through vectorization. With scalar instructions you just get the 1 lonely adder.
2. There is usually some overhead saved by using vector instructions. You load and store data in big chunks (up to 512 bits at a time on some recent Intel CPUs) and each loop iteration does more work so the loop overhead is generally lower in a relative sense<sup>2</sup>, and you need fewer instructions to do the same work so the CPU front-end overhead is lower, etc.

Finally, your dichotomy between *loops* and *vectorization* is odd. When you take non-vector code and vectorize it, you are generally going to end up with a loop if there was a loop there before, or not if there wasn't. The comparison is really between *scalar* (non-vector) instructions and vector instructions.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or at least 15 of the 16, perhaps one is used also to do scalar operations.

<sup>2</sup> You could probably get a similar loop-overhead benefit in the scalar case at the cost of a lot of loop unrolling.

Answer (score 12):

Vectorization is a type of parallel processing. It enables more computer hardware to be devoted to performing the computation, so the computation is done faster.

Many numerical problems, especially solution of partial differential equations, require the same calculation to be performed for a large number of cells, elements or nodes. Vectorization performs the calculation for many cells/elements/nodes in parallel.

Vectorization uses special hardware. Unlike a multicore CPU, for which each of the parallel processing units is a fully functional CPU core, vector processing units can perform only simple operations, and all the units perform the same operation at the same time, operating on a sequence of data values (a vector) simultaneously.

Comment: So the vectorized code has a radically different implementation?  It actually just distributes the operations amongst more cores?

If yes, does that mean that a single core CPU would see no benefits from vectorization, or are there sub-core hardware "units" (for lack of a better word) within each core that would still help speed things up?

Comment: @BenSandeen: Just for the record, no.  Each core has its own SIMD execution units, which get e.g. 4 units of work done for each 1 instruction it has to track through is pipeline.  Total throughput in operations per cycle across all cores is a product of `elements / vector` times `vectors/clock on each core` times `num_cores` - thread-level parallelism is another factor of speedup orthogonal to SIMD and instruction-level parallelism.

Comment: e.g. e.g. [FLOPS per cycle for sandy-bridge and haswell SSE2/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15655835) and [How do I achieve the theoretical maximum of 4 FLOPs per cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8389648).  Re: the internals of one core, see [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350024) (it doesn't.)  That doesn't address SIMD, just instruction-level parallelism within one core.  SIMD instructions are a way to widen just execution units / data paths, not the whole pipeline.