# How do I multiply each element in a list by a number?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can I multiply each element in `my_list` by 5? The output should be:

```
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: Using `map` is better than `for-loop`.

Comment: [And list comprehension is (almost always) better than `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) (and always better if `map` would require a `lambda`).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_new_list = [i * 5 for i in my_list]

>>> print(my_new_list)
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Note that a list comprehension is generally a more efficient way to do a `for` loop:

```
my_new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    my_new_list.append(i * 5)

>>> print(my_new_list)
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

As an alternative, here is a solution using the popular Pandas package:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(my_list)

>>> s * 5
0     5
1    10
2    15
3    20
4    25
dtype: int64
```

Or, if you just want the list:

```
>>> (s * 5).tolist()
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Finally, one *could* use `map`, although this is generally frowned upon.

```
my_new_list = map(lambda x: x * 5, my_list)
```

Using `map`, however, is generally less efficient.  Per a comment from [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) on a deleted answer to this question:

> The reason "no one" uses it is that, in general, it's a performance
> pessimization. The only time it's worth considering `map` in CPython is
> if you're using a built-in function implemented in C as the mapping
> function; otherwise, `map` is going to run equal to or slower than the
> more Pythonic listcomp or genexpr (which are also more explicit about
> whether they're lazy generators or eager `list` creators; on Py3, your
> code wouldn't work without wrapping the `map` call in `list`). If you're
> using `map` with a `lambda` function, stop, you're doing it wrong.

And another one of his comments posted to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35166654/2411802):

> Please don't teach people to use `map` with `lambda`; the instant you
> need a `lambda`, you'd have been better off with a list comprehension
> or generator expression. If you're clever, you can make `map` work
> without `lambda`s a lot, e.g. in this case, `map((5).__mul__, my_list)`, although in this particular case, thanks to some
> optimizations in the byte code interpreter for simple `int` math, `[x * 5 for x in my_list]` is faster, as well as being more Pythonic and simpler.

Comment: Variables name which starts with caps isn't Pythonic. And they're lists, not numbers. So I'd suggest use `l1` and `l2` as the variable name.

Comment: The use of 'l' as a variable is also discouraged because the letter 'l' and the number 1 are easily confused.  I used the variables in the OP's original question, and I believe your edit of the question did more harm than good.

Comment: If you feel my edit is bad, you can edit the question to improve it. Also, we can choose other variable rather than `l1` such as `l_1`, `list_1`, etc. These are all better than `Num_1`.

Answer (score 37):

A blazingly faster approach is to do the multiplication in a vectorized manner instead of looping over the list. Numpy has already provided a very simply and handy way for this that you can use.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> my_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> 
>>> my_list * 5
array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
```

Note that this doesn't work with Python's native lists. If you multiply a number with a list it will repeat the items of the as the size of that number.

```
In [15]: my_list *= 1000

In [16]: len(my_list)
Out[16]: 5000
```

If you want a pure Python-based approach using a list comprehension is basically the most Pythonic way to go.

```
In [6]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [7]: [5 * i for i in my_list]
Out[7]: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Beside list comprehension, as a pure functional approach, you can also use built-in `map()` function as following:

```
In [10]: list(map((5).__mul__, my_list))
Out[10]: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

This code passes all the items within the `my_list` to `5`'s `__mul__` method and returns an iterator-like object (in python-3.x). You can then convert the iterator to list using `list()` built in function (in Python-2.x you don't need that because `map` return a list by default).

### benchmarks:

```
In [18]: %timeit [5 * i for i in my_list]
463 ns ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit list(map((5).__mul__, my_list))
784 ns ± 10.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit [5 * i for i in my_list * 100000]
20.8 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit list(map((5).__mul__, my_list * 100000))
30.6 ms ± 169 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [24]: arr = np.array(my_list * 100000)

In [25]: %timeit arr * 5
899 µs ± 4.98 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm interested in why the numpy method is 'blazingly faster'? Could you possibly elaborate or point me towards some resources? I'm not sure what vectorization is.

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson Here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091979/why-is-vectorization-faster-in-general-than-loops

Comment: @Kasramvd That link is incorrect. The link discusses a different meaning of _vectorization_ as single-instruction-multiple-data (applying an operation to many data at once, as GPUs do). In the context of NumPy, _vectorization_ refers to using fast pre-compiled C loops to operate on a data sequence, rather than pure Python.

Comment: [Here's an accurate link](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html#Vectorized-Operations)

Answer (score 22):

You can do it in-place like so:

```
 l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 l[:] = [x * 5 for x in l]
```

This requires no additional imports and is very pythonic.

Comment: In addition: the concept is called _list comprehension_ if you want to look up more information about it.

Comment: I'd rather `l = [x * 5 for x in l]` over `l[:] = [x * 5 for x in l]`. The latter creates a new list, then uses it to overwrite the contents of `l` as opposed to just reassigning the reference which is cheaper. If you're actually worried about space, just iterate with a loop and mutate in-place.

Answer (score 6):

Since I think you are new with Python, lets do the long way, iterate thru your list using for loop and multiply and append each element to a new list.

using for loop

```
lst = [5, 20 ,15]
product = []
for i in lst:
    product.append(i*5)
print product
```

using list comprehension, this is also same as using for-loop but more 'pythonic'

```
lst = [5, 20 ,15]

prod = [i * 5 for i in lst]
print prod
```

Comment: How is the "long way" in any way better? It's longer—thus more difficult to read—and not any easier to write.

Comment: okay maybe you got the wrong impression on my title and i never said it was any better, just trying to show him how to do it without using comprehension. because on my experience when i was new in python i wasn't able to grasp the concept of comprehension easily.

Comment: Oh, okay. I can't directly relate because I started off with functional languages.

Comment: I see, well there. I edited the answer to also include the efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

With map (not as good, but another approach to the problem):

```
list(map(lambda x: x*5,[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]))
```

also, if you happen to be using numpy or numpy arrays, you could use this:

```
import numpy as np
list(np.array(x) * 5)
```

Comment: Why not use a lambda instead of defining timesfive function?

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import partial as p
from operator import mul
map(p(mul,5),my_list)
```

is one way you could do it ... your teacher probably knows a **much less complicated** way that was probably covered in class

Comment: You can do it without the import statements using a lambda expression. Also, your snippet returns a map object, which is useless unless cast to a list. list(map(lambda x: 5*x, my_list)).

Comment: @castle-bravo its usefulness depends on what you need to do with it ... there are many ways of accomplishing this solution (as I mention ...)

Comment: Please don't teach people to use `map` with `lambda`; the instant you need a `lambda`, you'd have been better off with a list comprehension or generator expression. If you're clever, you _can_ make `map` work without `lambda`s a lot, e.g. in this case, `map((5).__mul__, my_list)`, although in this particular case, thanks to some optimizations in the byte code interpreter for simple `int` math, `[x * 5 for x in my_list]` is faster, as well as being more Pythonic and simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying each element in `my_list` by `k`:

```
k = 5
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
result = list(map(lambda x: x * k, my_list))
```

resulting in: `[5, 10, 15, 20]`

Comment: This is probably the most elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I found it interesting to use list comprehension or map with just one object name x.
Note that whenever [x is reassigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465104/objects-having-same-name-refer-to-different-id-in-python), its id(x) changes, i.e. points to a different object.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
id(x)
2707834975552
x = [1.5 * x for x in x]
id(x)
2707834976576
x
[1.5, 3.0, 4.5]
list(map(lambda x : 2 * x / 3, x))
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
id(x) # not reassigned
2707834976576
x = list(map(lambda x : 2 * x / 3, x))
x
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
id(x)
2707834980928
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

#for Integer multiplier us   int(x).__mull__ with map    
var2 = list( map(int(2).__mul__,var1 ))
#for float multiplier
var2 = list( map(float(2.5).__mul__,var1 ))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Best way is to use list comprehension:**

```
def map_to_list(my_list, n):
# multiply every value in my_list by n
# Use list comprehension!
    my_new_list = [i * n for i in my_list]
    return my_new_list
# To test:
print(map_to_list([1,2,3], -1))
```

Returns:
[-1, -2, -3]

Comment: This just takes the accepted answer and turns it into a function. You could probably do that with more than half of the responses on SO, but it doesn't add anything and is not what the OP asked.