# While loop, double numbers in list

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

How would I produce a while loop, to double and therefore change the numbers in the following list?

Thank you.

```
numberList = [3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4]
```

This was my attempt

```
numberList = [3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4]

while numberList == numberList:
    numberList == numberList * 2
    print (numberList)
    break
```

Comment: `while numberList: print(numberList.pop()*2)`

Comment: Why are you asking for a while loop? There are _much_ better ways to do this in Python. For example: `numberList = [x*2 for x in numberList]`

Comment: @bigbounty That will double the length of the list, not the individual elements.

Comment: @Ray Toal, because, my Exercise question specifically asks for a while loop

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a site to do your homework for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number

Answer (score 0):

Although not the best way to solve the problem, this is a way of doing it using a while loop:

```
numberList = [3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4]
i=0
while i < len(numberList):
    numberList[i] *= 2
    i += 1

>>> numberList
[6, 10, 12, 4, 2, 10, 14, 8]
```

Notice that multiplying a list by an integer will output a list repeating the elements, so your attempt actually does something like this:

```
>>> [1,2,3]*2
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map list with a lambda function to perform the desired function!

```
numberList= [3, 5, 6, 2, 1, 5, 7, 4]
print map(lambda x:x*2,numberList)
```

Comment: Do you know why this seems to evaluate much faster than using `[x*2 for x in numberList]`?

Comment: take a look at @ninjagecko answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).