# python list multiply each value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I wonder how can I multiply each element in two different lists.

For example :

`list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]` 
`list_b = [10,20,30,40,50]`

I want to make it `1X10 2X20 3X30 4X40 5X50`

so that the result will be `10, 40, 90, 160, 250`

I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I multiply each element in a list by a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number)

Comment: `zip` in best method for this.[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` function as below.

```
>>> list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list_b = [10,20,30,40,50]
>>> [(x[0]*x[1]) for x in zip(list_a,list_b)]
[10, 40, 90, 160, 250]
```

Comment: `[a*b for a,b in zip(list_a,list_b)]` would be a little neater

Comment: or `list(map(operator.mul, list_a, list_b))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip()`:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_b = [10,20,30,40,50]
final = [k*v for k, v in zip(list_a, list_b)]
print final
```

Output:

```
[10, 40, 90, 160, 250]
```

Comment: For Python 3 you need to put `k,v` in parenthesis like this : `(k,v)`. Final line is `final = [k*v for (k, v) in zip(list_a, list_b)]`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Python 3 documentation said that parenthesis were needed but it's only the return part of the comprehension list.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [10,20,30,40,50]
print [a[i]*b[i] for i in range(len(b))]
```

This will helpful for you

Comment: You forgot to return their product!

Comment: i will understand question wrongly now i will change the output

Comment: Why `str` used in your solution.@adchoi_97 want `integer` item in list not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [i*i*10 for i in a]
```

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner version would be :

```
a,b = [1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,30,40,50]
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    print '%d x %d = '%(i,j),'%d units'% ((i*j))
```

Comment: you should use `zip` instead of `map`

Comment: Can you explain what difference does it makes?  I mean does it saves computing time or what?

Comment: That `map` is meant for *mapping operations* and `zip` is meant for zipping. You are using `zip` to do mapping. It is simply bad form.

Comment: You don't need the `None` argument, just `zip(a, b)`

Comment: Yeah, i checked!