# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' in multiply array and e-6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error was occoured like below in python.

```
[1,2,3]*1e-6

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Advisory for the duplicate closers: [Why do I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/) **should not** be used as a dupe target for questions like this, where there is a deliberately created list. That question is itself a duplicate of the canonical, [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427), for cases where one operand is a *string from user input* (which was intended to be also a number).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
ls=[1,2,3]
ls=np.array(ls)*1e-6
print(ls)
```

Hopefully this will work