# Objects having same name refer to different id in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

In the below code snippet, two objects named `div` are created at lines 1 and 2.

1. How does python differentiate between the two `div` objects created under the same scope?
2. When `id()` is applied on both objects, two different addresses are shown for the similar named objects. Why is this so?

```
def div(a,b):
    return a/b


print(id(div)) # id = 199......1640 ################################ line 1


def smart_div(func):
    def inner(a,b):
        if a<b:
            a,b=b,a
        return func(a,b)
    return inner


a = int(input("Enter 1st: "))
b = int(input("Enter 2nd: "))
div = smart_div(div)
print(id(div)) # id = 199......3224 ############################# line 2
print(div(a,b))
```

In legacy languages like C, one can't create two variables with the same name under same scope. But, in python this rule does not seem to apply.

Comment: `div = smart_div(div)` overwrites the `div` object. you're getting a different id value because it's no longer defined by `def div`. if you `print(div)` you can see that this object now refers to the function smart_div.

Comment: Okay. So the `div` variable now refers to the `smart_div()` and not the original `div` function. Thanks.

Comment: Objects dont "have names", names can refer to objects, but they are free to be re-assigned to different names at any time.

Comment: This topic is explained here very nicely: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In languages like C you can rename a variable with different values. That is how you update a value. In C they must have the same type though because C is a statically typed language. Python on the other hand is dynamically typed which means it doesn't track types. In programs there is a table where names are associated with values and when you defined `div` to a new value in the same scope it just wrote over that value because the second `div` came later. You can no longer access the function `div` any longer after the new `div` value has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

In Python everything (basically) is an object, and it does allow the re-use of variable names.

So I believe what you have done is to re-assign the variable name `div` from a name that pointed to a function, to a pointer to the function `smart_div`.

You should see that you are unable to access the old div function.

Comment: Yes, I am unable to access the old `div` function