# I have an array with 0 and 1 values. If I multiply this with -1, it results in empty array. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array "labels" with three thousand 0 and 1 values. If I multiply this with -1, it results in an empty array. I am not able to understand why it is resulting in 0?

Input

```
print(labels[0:10])
```

Output

```
['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
```

Now, if i do:

```
labels=labels*(-1)
print(labels)
```

It returns:

```
[]
```

I was expecting an array with 0 and -1 values. Please explain.

Comment: That appears to be a list, rather than an array.

Comment: Either use list comprehension: `print([int(x) * -1 for x in labels])` or numpy arrays `print(np.array(labels).astype(int)*-1)`. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35166717/9758194)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators `*` and `+` does not work the same on arrays and lists.

On an array, it computes the operation element-wise. On a list, it repeats or extends the list.

For instance:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a * 2)  # prints [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
print(np.array(a) * 2)  # prints np.array(2, 4, 6)
```

Hence, whatever the type of its element, a `list` object multiplied by -1 is the empty list. Convert your list into an array before doing your operation:

```py
labels = np.array(labels).astype(int) # Since you have a list of str
labels = labels * (-1)
print(labels)
```

Comment: Thank you. Very detailed explanation. How to resolve such doubts on our own? I am very new to programming.

Comment: There's no magic method other than practicing. Fortunately, you get used to it quickly enough, don't worry!

Comment: What am i doing wrong here?

    sent_splt=[['good', 'case,', 'excellent', 'value.'], ['great', 'for', 'the', 'jawbone.'],['tied', 'to', 'charger', 'for', 'conversations', 'lasting', 'more', 'than', '45', 'minutes.major', 'problems!!']]

    stop_set = ['the', 'a', 'an', 'i', 'he', 'she', 'they', 'to', 'of', 'it', 'from']

    x=[a for a in sent_splt if a not in stop_set]
    print(x)

It is not filtering the words. I am trying to filter stop words.

Comment: I think it is better that you post this as another question to use proper code formatting.

Comment: Actually, It is saying to post question after 1 day break from last 2 days for me. Basically I am not allowed to post question because of my previous question which was not as per stackoverflow standard. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it comes from the fact that `sent_splt` and `stop_set` do not contain the same type of object. The former contains `list` objects, the latter `str` objects. Hence, the condition `a not in stop_set` fo `a` being in `sent_splt` is always `True`.

Comment: Thank you @g2i  I think that is the case. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

Everything in the list is a string, multiplying a string by -1 is nothing:

```
print('1'*-1)
```

Prints nothing. Therefore in your case, the array is empty.

This can be fixed like this:

```
for i in range (len(labels)):
    labels[i]=int(labels[i])*-1
print(labels)
```

**Here, each of the elements is first converted to an integer before being multiplied.**

Or as *DerHamm* suggested:

```
labels = [int(labels[i]) * -1 for i in range(len(labels))]
```

Comment: FYI: Same solution as comprehension: labels = [int(labels[i]) * -1 for i in range(len(labels))]
Increases the performance slightly.

Comment: Thank you. Such a silly question from me! How to resolve such doubts on our own? I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication operation on lists in python does not `apply` the operation on each of the elements, but rather the whole list.

```
l = [1,2,3] * 2 # l == [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Taking this into account: multiplying by 0 would result in an empty list and anything below 0 wouldn't make sense, so it's also just an empty list (I believe this would make sense to raise an exception/valueerror here, but alas, that's not the case today).

What it looks like you want to do is multiply each element by -1:

```
l = [int(s) * -1 for s in labels]
# with maybe an additional conversion back to strings:
l = map(str, l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list has `str` values. So do this:

```
In [1945]: l = ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
In [1949]: [int(i) *(-1) for i in l]                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[1949]: [0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to int and multiply using a list comprehension:

```
list_of_numbers = ['0', '1', '0', '1']
a = [int(i) * -1 for i in list_of_numbers]
print(a)
```

result:

```
[0, -1, 0, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use arithmetic directly on the list and your list apparantely contains strings so try this:

```
test = ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0']
test = [x*-1 for x in list(map(int, test))]
test

[0, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]
```