# two dimensional python array manipulation does no yield desired result

Tags: python

I am stumped by this silly and simple issue. Just can't understand what is wrong here!

```
a = [[0]*3]*2
print(a)
a[1][2] = 1
print(a)
```

i get the following output

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
[[0,0,1],[0,0,1]]
```

I don't understand why I see two 1, while I changed only one of them. How do I change only one of them?

Comment: What is your desired output? This can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number

Answer (score 2):

by doing

```
a = [[0]*3]
```

You created an array

> [0,0,0]

You then copied the reference to this array when you did

```
a = [[0]*3]*2
```

As a result changing one causes the other to change. This is known as a shallow copy.

What you want is a deepcopy and can be achieved by the copy's library deepcopy() method

Hence, do this instead:

```
 import copy
 a = [[0]*3]
 a += copy.deepcopy(a)
 a[1][2] = 1
 print(a)
```

> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]

Comment: how do i solve it. copy.copy() does not work

Comment: @ManishAgarwal See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `[[0]*3]*2` is creating two smaller lists that are both associated to the same data value (because of the *2). To fix this, you would just want to define it in a different way that doesn't do this, for example:

`a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`
or
`a = [[0]*3] + [[0]*3]`