# Trying to update an array by changing its value in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, updating

I am trying to alter the values in an array.
I, first created an array from a previous array by setting a condtion. The previous array was called Sales_Salary and the new array is called index which was made by using where(Sales_Salary<200000).
Now, I want to update index by multiplying the values by 1.2.

Here is my code:

```
index = np.where(Sales_Salary<20000)
print(Sales_Salary[index])
```

How do I do this?
Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: What you ask is probably answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number

Comment: @ApostolisKasselouris Thanks for that post. I did not realise that all I had to do was to multiply Sales_Salary[index]*1.2.

Comment: @Pythonlearner Yes, it has. It seems that I forgot that you could do it directly.