# How do I call a math function on each of the items obtained from a list from .split in an input?

Tags: python, split-function

```
def bill_cal():
  split_amount = bill_amount_list * (1-cashback_rate) / person_split_no
  print(f"each person should pay {split_amount}.")

bill_amount = input("How much is the bill? You can enter multiple bills separated by comma.\n")
bill_amount_list = bill_amount.split(",")
cashback_rate = float(input("Is there any credit card cashback on the bills? 2% = 0.02\n"))
person_split_no = int(input("How many people are splitting the bill?"))
for bill in map(float, bill_amount_list):
  bill_cal()
```

I am trying to cast float on each item obtained from `bill_amount.split(",")`, and perform the `bill_cal()` function, but got below error:

```
How much is the bill? You can enter multiple bills separarted by comma.
100,200
Is there any credit card cashback on the bills? 2% = 0.02
.02
How many people are splitting the bill?2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    bill_cal()
  File "main.py", line 2, in bill_cal
    split_amount = bill_amount_list * (1-cashback_rate) / person_split_no
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I multiply each element in a list by a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

You are "multiplying" your `bill_amount_list` which is... well, a `list`. Sequences can be "multiplied" by `int` (meaning you will repeat the sequence), but not by `float`, hence your error.

Pass your `bill` to the function, and use it in the computation:

```
def bill_cal(amount):
    split_amount = amount * (1-cashback_rate) / person_split_no
#...
for bill in map(float,bill_amount_list):
  bill_cal(bill)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and it works. Now I want to add the sum of the split_amount, I tried math.fsum but it returns that TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable, is there another way of adding the sum of the amount?

Comment: Do you want the total for each person? Sum the amounts in your list and call `bill_cal` one last time with that amount

Comment: yes it should be total for each person. I am not sure how do I get the list of split_amount?

Comment: You almost have it already: `sum(map(float,bill_amount_list))`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the function with a local variable.
Also it's good practice to check your input as well like this:

```
if item.isnumeric():
    'call the function'
```